# php ignore specific compile error

Tags: php, error-handling

Is there any way to config php to ignore one specific error. In my case I need to ignore only this complie error:

**Compile Error: Cannot inherit previously-inherited or override constant**

I know, you probably tell me not to do this (breaks lsp and so), but this is important to fix in my project.

Comment: PHP, compile? Huh. Are you using PHPLint or something?

Comment: This is a [bug in PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63359&edit=1) for those wondering. I think the last comment sums it up: `PHP developers do not seem to understand basic concepts in OOP.`

Comment: lets say my class implements 2 interfaces from other libraries that both have the same constants with the name "name". What can I do in this case?

Comment: @thatidiotguy, The PHP **language** is interpreted. But PHP calls it a compile error whenever it fails to startup (when a require fail for instance)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **set_error_handler** function for handling errors. 
Use it with common sense.

Comment: Yeah... no. It's better to fix the error (even though it's a bug in the language) with some other method than squelching the error

Comment: Yes, i agree.. But his requirement is typical. Its up to him to decide. Since no sufficient details provided, we cant tell anything.